# Function multiplicativity

Tags: nt.number-theory, multiplicative-number-theory

Is this a multiplicative function? $ \displaystyle \sum_{a=1 \atop (a,q)=1}^{q}e^{-2\pi i\frac{a}{q}c_q(da)F}=T(q)$,where $d,F\in \mathbb{N}$ and $c_q(da)$ - Ramanujan's sum https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have far have you tested for multiplicativity?

Comment: @Somos I tried to get rid of the dependence $a,q$; $c_q(da)=c_q(d)$because then the function would be multiplicative, then I tried to use the multiplicative property of the Ramanujan's sum, but all attempts were in vain.

Comment: I assume that $d$ and $F$ are fixed. If $d=F=1$ then $T(3)=-1,T(4)=2,T(12)=4$ which is not multiplicative. Again, how far have you tested for multiplicativity?

Comment: @Somos I have not tested for exact values. Thank you for this testing.

Comment: @Somos Can you do some more calculations? I'll take that as an answer.

Comment: After some more testing, it seems that always $T(u\,v)\ne T(u)T(v)$ for some $u\in\{2,3,5\}$ and $2<v<10$ with $1=\text{gcd}(u,v)$ depending on $d$ and $F$.

Comment: @Somos Thank you very much.